# Newbie javascript question on method chaining and passing objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to teach myself javascript and d3 at the same time, but most of my programming experience doesn't include object oriented stuff.  Anyway, I'm trying to understand the passing of objects as parameters when using method chaining.  Specifically (example here comes from the Fullstack D3 book) I can construct an object (in this case, an array representing bins of a histogram) like this:

```
const binsGenerator = d3.bin().domain(xScale.domain()).value(metricAccessor).thresholds(12)
const test = binsGenerator(dataset)
```

That makes sense.  But why is it that if I pass my data object directly to d3.bin(), it returns a function, instead of the same array I got when I used the binsGenerator function.  Specifically, if I try this:

```
const test = d3.bin(dataset).domain(xScale.domain()).value(metricAccessor).thresholds(12)
```

test is a function, instead of the same array I got when I used binsGenerator. I'm confused by this, since the D3 documentation on d3.bins (https://github.com/d3/d3-array) says that calling d3.bin() with an argument specified returns an array of bins.   I'm guessing this is a pretty basic javascript question having to do with method chaining . . . but quick research on that on my end doesn't seem to be getting me anywhere.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You got a function back in the first example as well, and then called it in the second line. To do it in one line, you would call it with your data at the end of the chain. `const test = d3.bin().domain(xScale.domain()).value(metricAccessor).thresholds(12)(dataset)`

Comment: From the [documentation](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-bin#cell-1300): *'d3.bin doesn’t generate the buckets directly: **it returns a function** that can be parametrized before it is applied to the data to generate the buckets.'* (emphasis mine)

Comment: Ah, ok.  Thanks.  But still: hmmmmm.  Doesn't that same documentation also say that passing an argument to d3.bin() causes the function to return an array?  Specifically: 

'# bin(data):

Bins the given iterable of data samples. Returns an array of bins, where each bin is an array containing the associated elements from the input data.'

Comment: That [bin](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/main/README.md#_bin) is referring to the function returned by `d3.bin()` (`const bin = d3.bin()`). If you look at the [source](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/main/src/bin.js) you can see that `d3.bin()` defines no parameters, so any passed are just ignored. At the very least you would need to call `const test = d3.bin()(dataset)` which would return an array as you are expecting using the default parameters.

Comment: Oh, ok.  Thanks very much! That really helps.  Related question: is there a simple way (besides looking at the source code, which is above my programming pay grade) to determine whether a function always returns another function, vs. returning an object if the call to the function includes an argument?

Comment: Glad it helped, and take a little time to read through the source I linked. It's not too complicated, and even if you don't get everything that is happening it might reveal something. You can test the return type for each call `console.log(typeof d3.bin())` and `console.log(typeof d3.bin(dataset))`